# LinkedIn API: "Get My Connections" - is it still possible?

Tags: web-services, rest, linkedin-api

There are plenty of threads on this that now seem to be depreciated.

LinkedIn appear to have a new API in place and I can't find if/how it's possible to get a list of my logged-in-user's connections. Is this no longer available? I'm not seeing anything in the [ApiGee LinkedIn Console](http://apigee.com/console/linkedin)

If not, is there anything stopping me from creating a `casperjs` script that goes to [this page](http://www.linkedin.com/contacts/?filter=recent&trk=nav_responsive_tab_network#?filter=recent&trk=nav_responsive_tab_network) and scrapes the connection data?

Answer (score -1):

Scraping data from LinkedIn is specifically prohibited via their User Agreement:  https://www.linkedin.com/legal/user-agreement

Comment: Well that's unfortunate. Is there any other way to get a list of my own connections?